# add user proFtpd with plesk on Debian

Tags: debian, ftp

We're using plesk with proftpd (on debian5). I want to add a ftpuser USER for the directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/httpdocs/test

So I added a system user 
`useradd USER -s /bin/false -d /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/httpdocs/test` and setted the pass with passwd.
I also tried it with shell, same result.

But I'm not able to login through ftp.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check the directory permissions. If that fails, read the logs. If even that fails, be more verbose in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is possibly in /var/log/secure, although saying that I've generally found FTP logs to be lacking. The directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/httpdocs directory only be executable for psaserv and the username for that vhost (as seen by Plesk).

If you have ACL available (not sure for Debian 5), you could try:
`setfacl -m user:USER:r-x /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/httpdocs`
`setfacl -m -R user:USER:rwx /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/httpdocs/test`
`setfacl -m -R -d user:USER:rwx /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/httpdocs/test`

If you get an error complaining about the syntax, you probably need to remount the partition with ACL. Try:
`mount -o remount,acl /var` or `mount -o remount,acl /` or whatever the relevant partition is.

If not, I'd advise not giving full permissions to the any user, and instead create a new dummy group for it to replace psaserv for that directory, so, roughly:
`groupadd your_dummy_group`
`for i in $(lid -g psaserv | cut -f2 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"("); do usermod -aG your_dummy_group $i; done`
`chgrp your_dummy_group /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/httpdocs`

That will let you into the directory. As for reading/writing, you'll need to do the same as above except recursively for the directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/httpdocs/test and with the group psacln (which, I believe but don't have an installation to test, gives full access to the directory - if not, you'll have more permissions to modify).

Obviously you could 777 the whole thing, but it would be a bad idea.

Comment: I dont have a file /var/log/secure, also i dont have acl. But I tried 777 for testing and it is not working.

Comment: I love how you went straight to the "bad idea" and ignored the well presented option in the middle. It's /var/log/access.log I believe on Debian based systems, sorry for the mix up. Also, what did you set to 777?

Comment: yes it's not the nice way, but i want it to work first. and then i work it up the clean way ;-). Also have no access.log. I have a proftpd folder but all logs are emtpy. But I found /opt/psa/var/log/xferlog (from proftpd.conf as TransferLog), but there are also no relevant data.

Comment: What did you make 777? Which command did you run?

Comment: /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/httpdocs/test is 777 and owned by www-data

Comment: As I said above, /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/httpdocs is the problem - it doesn't matter what permissions you give to test, it won't get that far.

Comment: oh overseen that ... sry. now it works. Great BIG THX